# HTML5 canvas flying through space stars animation using React Typescript

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, react-typescript

I am trying to make star animation using react typescript but I am new in react ts [this is the reference link and this animation made in canvas and js](https://codepen.io/bts/pen/BygMzB)

in my code, I added the same way but getting too many errors

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
const Canvas = () => {
    let canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
    let canvasCtxRef = React.useRef<CanvasRenderingContext2D | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Initialize
        if (canvasRef.current) {
            var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam: any) {
                var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                    sParameterName,
                    i;

                for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }
            };

            var field = canvasRef.current;
            var f = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
            
            var stars = {};
            var starIndex = 0;
            var numStars = 0;
            var acceleration:any = 1;
            var starsToDraw:any = (field.width * field.height) / 200;
            if (getUrlParameter("stars")) {
                starsToDraw = getUrlParameter("stars");
            }
            if (getUrlParameter("accel")) {
                acceleration = getUrlParameter("accel");
            }


            function Star() {
                this.X = field.width / 2;
                this.Y = field.height / 2;

                this.SX = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
                this.SY = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

                var start = 0;

                if (field.width > field.height)
                    start = field.width;
                else
                    start = field.height;

                this.X += this.SX * start / 10;
                this.Y += this.SY * start / 10;

                this.W = 1;
                this.H = 1;

                this.age = 0;
                this.dies = 500;

                starIndex++;
                stars[starIndex] = this;

                this.ID = starIndex;
                this.C = "#ffffff";
            }

            Star.prototype.Draw = function () {
                this.X += this.SX;
                this.Y += this.SY

                this.SX += this.SX / (50 / acceleration);
                this.SY += this.SY / (50 / acceleration);

                this.age++;

                if (this.age == Math.floor(50 / acceleration) || this.age == Math.floor(150 / acceleration) || this.age == Math.floor(300 / acceleration)) {
                    this.W++;
                    this.H++;
                }

                if (this.X + this.W < 0 || this.X > field.width ||
                    this.Y + this.H < 0 || this.Y > field.height) {
                    delete stars[this.ID];
                    numStars--;
                }

                f.fillStyle = this.C;
                f.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, this.W, this.H);
            }

            field.width = window.innerWidth;
            field.height = window.innerHeight;

            function draw() {
                if (field.width != window.innerWidth)
                    field.width = window.innerWidth;
                if (field.height != window.innerHeight)
                    field.height = window.innerHeight;

                // Play with the "a" value to create streams...it's fun!
                f.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
                f.fillRect(0, 0, field.width, field.height);

                for (var i = numStars; i < starsToDraw; i++) {
                    new Star();
                    numStars++;
                }

                for (var star in stars) {
                    stars[star].Draw();
                }
            }

            // Original timing of the screensaver
            setInterval(draw, 40);

        }
    }, []);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>;
}

export default Canvas;
```

getting too many errors I tried searching solutions regarding `HTML` canvas with react typescript but there are only a few tutorials available which not able to help me if anyone know how I can solve this issue pl help me... thanks :)